# Change Session Timeout on fly in ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

Is there a way to change `Session Timeout` on fly in ASP.NET MVC 5 globally without restarting application?

I know we can do

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {            
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10),
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
                CookieName = ".MyApp1_Authentication",
                SlidingExpiration = true
            });
}
```

But is there a way to do it in other places of the application? Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Close to a duplicate question but to answer this specifically, you can do this

```
  HttpContext.Current.Session.Timeout = 20;
```